# Objective-C Return Method-Declared Object From Nested Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, objective-c-blocks

In the following block of code, the first method calls the second method, which should return the results of a geocoding process:

```
- (void)foo {
    CLPlacemark *currentMark = [self reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location];
}

- (CLPlacemark *)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    __block CLPlacemark *placeMark;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if ([placemarks firstObject])
                placeMark = [placemarks firstObject];
        }
    }];
    return placeMark;
}
```

However, since the program's execution, doesn't wait for the geocoding to complete before continuing (hence the completion block), there is always a danger that the `placeMark` variable will be returned uninstantiated before the geocoding process finishes and the completion block is called. I've faced the same predicament when making HTTP requests to web services whose results will not return for an indeterminate amount of time.

The only solution I've seen thus far is to nest the all the code from `foo` in the geocoder's completion block, which quickly becomes very ugly and difficult to maintain.

What is the best way for the `currentMark` variable in `foo` to be set to the result of the second method's completion block without nesting it in the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best way to handle this issue overall is to use delegates. That way, the flow of the program isn't obstructed by waiting an indeterminate amount of time for the completion block to return.

Here's a short example of what I've decided on:

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if ([placemarks firstObject])
                [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(done:) withObject:[placemarks firstObject];
        }
    }];
    return placeMark;
}
```

In hindsight, this actually seems rather elegant. The control flow of the main thread (i.e. UI presentation), isn't hindered in any way, and the view controller querying data can essentially be "notified" that data has loaded, rather than directly demanding a returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the function return a value, just add a callback block to return the value.

Try this:

```
- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location withCallback:(void(^)(CLPlacemark *resultPlacemark, NSError *error))_block {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        _block([placemark objectAtIndex:0], error);
    }];
}
```

and then foo would be

```
 - (void)foo {
            __block CLPlacemark *currentMark;
            [self reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location withCallback:(CLPlacemark *mark, NSError *error) {
               currentMark = mark;
            }];
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, that kind of just reverses the problem, though. You still end up with a completion block that you then have to layer all your additional code in to ensure that `currentMark` in `foo` is not nil.

Comment: The current mark is returned from the geocoder in a block so you don't really have a choice. Why is it an issue?

Comment: Well if you abide by the methodology you wrote (or my current one for that matter), you eventually end up with a ton of braces all over the place as you make additional requests in the completion blocks of the previous ones. It's just not very elegant.

Comment: Haha. Yes. Lots of ugly braces.  Asynchronous programming is hard.  But we have no idea who is calling foo, so it's assumed the caller doesn't need to block.  Now you're getting into linking controllers and views and what not with delegates.